# Ember.js cancel bubble on custom view elements inside {{link-to}}

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I've got a list of items where each row is a `{{link-to}}`
Inside this link I have a title and a button. 
[image: Items list]

Basically I don't want to propagate to `{{link-to}}`action on other elements. 
I was easy enough for the button `{{action 'buttonClick' this bubbles=false}}`.

But the title is actually a simple `<span>` which has a Jquery plugin attached (X-editable) which is triggered when I click on the `<span>`

[image: X-editable in action]

It works fine, except `{{link-to}}` is triggered each time I click on the `{{span}}` and event worse `Save` and `Cancel` actions on X-editable are intercepted by `{{link-to}}`

As soon as I move the `<span>` outside the `{{link-to}}` element it works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: what if you use `jQuery's` `stopPropagation` e.g. `$('.test-span').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();});` does it behave as you require?

Comment: @melc yeah, I already tried. It stopped propagating only on initial click. But when the little box pops up, its actions are still propagating. I would really hate to hack the plugin, inserting ``e.stopPropagation()`` here and there...

Comment: actually no need to hack the plugin, just the mentioned `stopPropagation` hack. Required to only call `e.stopPropagation()` for all elements that are contained within the `{{link-to}}` helper. For example, `$(document).on('click','#test span,#test a',function(e){e.stopPropagation();});`. I propose the delegated flavour of `on` (https://api.jquery.com/on/) if the plugin you are using adds elements dynamically at a later point.

Comment: Sweet! I modified it a bit to match my ember classes and it worked! put it in as an answer and I'll accept it for future generations to enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm happy you made it work, I'll post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use jQuery's `stopPropagation`
 e.g. `$('.test-span').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();});`

It is actually required to only call `e.stopPropagation()` for all elements that are contained within the `{{link-to}}` helper. For example, 
`$(document).on('click','#test span,#test a',function(e){e.stopPropagation();});`

I propose the delegated flavour of `on` (http://api.jquery.com/on) if the plugin used adds elements dynamically at a later point.